# External file JQuery function not trigered in Internet Explorer11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11

I have worked in JQuery 3.3.1. The button link function is not trigered in Internet Explorer. Even the same code is working fine with Chrome, firefox and Edge

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<a href="#" class="btn btn-social btn-facebook" id="btnPopupFacebook" onclick="FBcheckLoginState()"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
<a href="#" class="forgot-password" id="ForgotPasswordLink">Forgot Password?</a>

<script>
  function FBcheckLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      if (response.status == 'unknown' && response.authResponse == null) {
        FB.login(function(response) {
          if (response.authResponse) {
            FBcheckLoginState();
          } else {
            //console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
          }
        }, {
          scope: 'public_profile,email',
          return_scopes: true
        });
      } else {
        statusChangeCallback(response);
      }
    });
  }

  $('#ForgotPasswordLink').click(function() {
    $('#signin').hide();
    $('#ForgotPassword').show();
    $('#ForgotPassword').css('opacity', '1');
  });
</script>
```

I'm getting the error:

> 'FBcheckLoginState' is undefined in console.

The click function is not fired.

Comment: I've tested and your code works fine in IE11. The error I get is `FB is undefined`, which is expected as you didn't include the FB SDK in the snippet.

Comment: I also just tested the code in IE 11 and its working just fine. Do you have a published version we could examine?

Comment: Using internal script, then its working fine...When i moved to external file `<script src="~/sso-login.js"></script>`, in that case the file is not loaded. Even i have put the file link with in `<head>` tag

Comment: Please check the external js file path, try to use " <script src="sso-login.js"></script>" to add the js file in the head tag.